# [SPARQL/DBPedia]make a query with a zip-code and get some information about the city

Tags: geolocation, rdf, sparql, dbpedia

Hey,
i want to make a query with a zip-code to get some informations about the City.
But how it works?

Can someone tell me how the query must look?

Greetz sheepy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possbile that the FILTER has to be included into the Where brackets{}?

SELECT * WHERE {
?s a onto:Place .
?s geo:lat ?lat .
?s geo:long ?long .
FILTER ( ?long > YOUR_LONG - radius && ?long < YOUR_LONG + radius &&
lat > YOUR_LAT - radius && ?lat < YOUR_LAT + radius)
}
LIMIT 100

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if dbpedia holds zip-code data. What they have are the geographical coordinates of all the resources that can be geographically positioned.

You could extract those coordinates with queries similar to :

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT * WHERE {
?s a onto:Place .
?s geo:lat ?lat .
?s geo:long ?long .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

This query would get for you all places with their coordinates.
You could use Google MAPs API to get the coordinates for certain zip-code and then get places around that zip-code by filtering the coordinates in the SPARQL query.

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT * WHERE {
?s a onto:Place .
?s geo:lat ?lat .
?s geo:long ?long .
} FILTER ( ?long > YOUR_LONG - radius && ?long < YOUR_LONG + radius &&
lat > YOUR_LAT - radius && ?lat < YOUR_LAT + radius)
LIMIT 100
```

If you explain a bit more your use case I might be able to help better.

Another hint ... you could use also [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/)